# zend user auth by submitting user credentials from remote android device

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

We have developed a web site, online magazine store for android device, there is also an android app that loads the website as web view. Every device has a username, password and a device ID which is sent as post during the loading of web view.

My requirement is :

- The site should load only if the login credential supplied (post) from the android device is valid.

Where should I check the validity of the the credential?
I mean should I write a plugin or whether the checking has to done in bootstrap. I dont need any group based access control all users have the same privilege.

Please show some example with necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation here would be to use an Action Helper that checks for your $POST variable and redirects/blocks the user as required.

[Writing your own action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown) is not difficult and once you've tried it you won't be able to stop! [Matthew Weier O'Phinney has written an excellent blog post](http://mwop.net/blog/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html) that will be useful to you too.